# PHP preg_replace_callback chokes on "a:" values

Tags: php, regex, string

we've built a platform that allows users to add special <# tags #> inside of HTML input attributes... i used a preg_replace_callback to find all of the matching inputs in a form body string, and then it processes them and returns a modified string for the whole form including all the updated input elements.

i've narrowed down the issue to the very last attribute value starting with any series of letters and then a colon.   that is the only case that breaks the regex and makes it throw a "PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR"

```
<input onclick="javascript:blah();">
```

would break it.   i've already told the developers that they should use onclick="blah()" instead, but this used to work, and browsers support it, so they still want it to work.

```
<input onclick=":blah();">
```

doesn't break it.  this makes me think it's some kind of internal storage is using "key:value" pairs to store back references or something, and the data it's parsing is itself breaking that data schema.

a real strange thing is that the code produces different results on google app engine PHP, and on PHP 5.3.3 running on centos... the native PHP throws in the error in more of the cases.

here is test code and the test results:

```
<?php

process_string("<input type=\"button\" value=\"update google doc\" onclick=\"javascript:getgoogledoc();\">");
process_string("<input type=\"button\" value=\"update google doc\" onclick=\":getgoogledoc();\">");
process_string("<input type=\"button\" value=\"update google doc\" onclick=\"getgoogledoc();\">");
process_string("<input type=\"button\" value=\"update google doc\" onclick=\"getgoogledoc();\" newattribute=\"javascript:test();\">");
process_string("<input type=\"button\" value=\"update google doc\" onclick=\"a:getgoogledoc();\">");
process_string("<input type=\"a:button\" value=\"javascript:update google doc\">");
process_string("<input type=\"button\" value=\"javascript:update google doc\" <# this makes it match #> onclick=\"javascript:getgoogledoc();\">");
process_string("<input type=\"button\" value=\"javascript:update google doc\" <# this makes it match #> onclick=\"getgoogledoc();\">");

function process_string($string) {
    echo "<p><b>NEW TEST</b><br />initial string:<br />";
    echo htmlspecialchars($string);
    $string = preg_replace_callback(
        '/<\s*input\s+((\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\'(\\\\\\\\|\\\\\'|[^\'])*\'|"(\\\\\\\\|\\\\"|[^"])*"|(\w+))|\s*(\w+))*\s*)<#\s*(.*?)\s*#>((\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\'(\\\\\\\\|\\\\\'|[^\'])*\'|"(\\\\\\\\|\\\\"|[^"])*"|(\w+))|\s*(\w+))*\s*)(\/\s*|)>/is',
        function($matches) {
            echo "<br />matched something...";
            return $matches[0];
        },
        $string
    );
    echo "<br />ok... ran the regex replace callback... string is now:<br />";
    echo htmlspecialchars($string);
    $last_error = preg_last_error();
    echo "<br />the last regex error was: $last_error";
    if($last_error==PREG_NO_ERROR) {
        echo "<br />that is a PREG_NO_ERROR";
    }
    if($last_error==PREG_INTERNAL_ERROR) {
        echo "<br />that is a PREG_INTERNAL_ERROR";
    }
    if($last_error==PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR) {
        echo "<br />that is a PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR";
    }
    if($last_error==PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR) {
        echo "<br />that is a PREG_RECURSION_LIMIT_ERROR";
    }
    if($last_error==PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR) {
        echo "<br />that is a PREG_BAD_UTF8_ERROR";
    }
    if($last_error==PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET_ERROR) {
        echo "<br />that is a PREG_BAD_UTF8_OFFSET_ERROR";
    }
}

?>
```

RESULTS:

```
NEW TEST
initial string:
<input type="button" value="update google doc" onclick="javascript:getgoogledoc();">
ok... ran the regex replace callback... string is now:

the last regex error was: 2
that is a PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR

NEW TEST
initial string:
<input type="button" value="update google doc" onclick=":getgoogledoc();">
ok... ran the regex replace callback... string is now:
<input type="button" value="update google doc" onclick=":getgoogledoc();">
the last regex error was: 0
that is a PREG_NO_ERROR

NEW TEST
initial string:
<input type="button" value="update google doc" onclick="getgoogledoc();">
ok... ran the regex replace callback... string is now:
<input type="button" value="update google doc" onclick="getgoogledoc();">
the last regex error was: 0
that is a PREG_NO_ERROR

NEW TEST
initial string:
<input type="button" value="update google doc" onclick="getgoogledoc();" newattribute="javascript:test();">
ok... ran the regex replace callback... string is now:

the last regex error was: 2
that is a PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR

NEW TEST
initial string:
<input type="button" value="update google doc" onclick="a:getgoogledoc();">
ok... ran the regex replace callback... string is now:

the last regex error was: 2
that is a PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR

NEW TEST
initial string:
<input type="a:button" value="javascript:update google doc">
ok... ran the regex replace callback... string is now:
<input type="a:button" value="javascript:update google doc">
the last regex error was: 0
that is a PREG_NO_ERROR

NEW TEST
initial string:
<input type="button" value="javascript:update google doc" <# this makes it match #> onclick="javascript:getgoogledoc();">
matched something...
ok... ran the regex replace callback... string is now:
<input type="button" value="javascript:update google doc" <# this makes it match #> onclick="javascript:getgoogledoc();">
the last regex error was: 0
that is a PREG_NO_ERROR

NEW TEST
initial string:
<input type="button" value="javascript:update google doc" <# this makes it match #> onclick="getgoogledoc();">
matched something...
ok... ran the regex replace callback... string is now:
<input type="button" value="javascript:update google doc" <# this makes it match #> onclick="getgoogledoc();">
the last regex error was: 0
that is a PREG_NO_ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR` occurs due to excessive backtracking and can be handled using [Possessive Quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) 
Give this modification to the regex a try (notice that I've added `+` quantifier at the location indicated by ^)-

```
'/<\s*input\s+((\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\'(\\\\\\\\|\\\\\'|[^\'])*\'|"(\\\\\\\\|\\\\"|[^"])*"|(\w+))|\s*(\w+))*+\s*)<#\s*(.*?)\s*#>((\s*(\w+)\s*=\s*(\'(\\\\\\\\|\\\\\'|[^\'])*\'|"(\\\\\\\\|\\\\"|[^"])*"|(\w+))|\s*(\w+))*\s*)(\/\s*|)>/is'
                                                                                                       ^
```

Comment: thank you very much... it works and i haven't found any regressions